# If AI had been developing for 5000+ years and the singularity happened, what would be the last human jobs left on earth?

Tags: science-fiction

In the future, say in 5,000+ years, if AI had been developing that whole time and the singularity happened, what would be the last human jobs left on earth?

I'm interested to hear from the community regarding this. Let's include that the AI is self-aware and has been for some time, and is writing its own software upgrades. Anything along the lines of Automatons is fair game for speculation and not included in the question. I am trying to visualize the final few remaining jobs for humans in this setting.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133285/discussion-on-question-by-luckyclover-if-ai-had-been-developing-for-5000-years).

Answer (score 4):

Name a human need and I will tell you how to automate it.

Need groceries? From growing crops to transporting them to a delivery center and then to your house, every step in the way can be automated.

Wanna talk to a doctor to see what that cough is about? Some AI's are already better than humans at diagnosing diseases. Blood, urine and stool collection can also all be automatized.

Do you wish to write and publish a fantasy novel? AI's are getting better and better at it. [They are already able to write an ending to Game of Thrones on par with the [redacted] that HBO produced](https://winteriscoming.net/2019/06/14/game-of-thrones-series-finale-rewritten-by-ai-acted-out-funny-or-die/). It is a matter of years now before they can write something that makes sense.

Need a lawyer? Lawyers nowadays are using IBM's Watson more and more, and Watson is learning from them. In the future Watson might replace them.

The only jobs left for humans will range from meatbag era reenactment actors to machine court jesters.

I recommend reading [the Mercury chapter of *Nine Planets Without Intelligent Life*](https://www.bohemiandrive.com/mercury). It depicts the end of humanity on the hands of AI exactly how I picture it. Not via war, famine nor pestilence, but because people will prefer to copulate with AI and will have no motivation to keep a minimum viable birth rate.

Comment: If people become unconfortable on meeting a robot doctor programmable matter could be used to simulate a human medic with any looks.

Answer (score 4):

Butlers and Geisha, probably escorts and possibly prostitutes too.

Butlers and Geisha are not actually employed for the physical services they provide but for the social status that comes with being able to employ a *person*, a professional, to do those things. AI/robots can provide the same services but are not, and cannot be, the same kind of status symbol.

Escorts have a similar role but could be replaced with sufficiently realistic simulacra because they don't serve the same people in the same space day in and day out, i.e.you could conceivably pass off a robot escort as human, for one or two nights. Escorts and prostitutes will probably become very niche with the market reduced to those who are uncomfortable with the idea of an artificial in those roles and those who can pay for the bragging rights that go with being able to pay for a real human in a role traditional taken by a 'bot.

Answer (score 2):

Litter box cleaners.

Yes, there are some limited robotic litter cleaners already, but the humans still have to deal with keeping those clean.

Cats didn't domesticate humanity into the roll of cat slaves just so humanity could pass the job off to robots. One way or another, humans will be forced to clean up after their furry overlords.

Comment: Yes, true. Never thought it, but yeah. Robots won't be able to be as good pet owners as we will.